# Core-plot: How to plot a graph with Y Axis on mean value?

Tags: ios, plot, core-plot

I have set up a graph with core plot that show an animation when in the presence of new data to display. I followed the example code of CorePlot to show new data animated in the graph.

This is the situation:

- I have to show the trend of a value (for example the speed)
- X-axis: speed value that I want to draw
- Y-axis: time value and I want that the axis is always centered on the average value currently available in the chart
- Each value in the graph must be visible, so I have to widen the range of the x axis to hold all the data.

Now the Y-axis moves at each new value. without being "anchored" in the middle.

This is my initial setup for chart:

```
- (void)configureHost {

    self.hostViewTop = [(CPTGraphHostingView *) [CPTGraphHostingView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height/3, 2*self.view.frame.size.width/5, self.view.frame.size.height/1.5)];
    self.hostViewTop.collapsesLayers = NO;
    [self.hostViewTop setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
    [self.hostViewTop setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];
    self.hostViewTop.allowPinchScaling = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:self.hostViewTop];
}

- (void) configurePlots{

    CPTGraph *graph = self.hostViewTop.hostedGraph;
    CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;

//    1 - Create the three plots

    ...  

//    2 - Set up plot space

    plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromUnsignedInteger(0) length:CPTDecimalFromUnsignedInteger(MAX_DATA_ON_CHART)];
    plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromUnsignedInteger(0) length:CPTDecimalFromUnsignedInteger(MAX_VALUE)];

//    4 - Create styles and symbols

    ...
}

- (void)configureAxes {

    // 1 - Create styles

    ...

    // 2 - Get axis set

    CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *) self.hostViewTop.hostedGraph.axisSet;

    // X axis

    CPTXYAxis *x = axisSet.xAxis;
    x.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic;
    x.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromUnsignedInteger(0);
    x.minorGridLineStyle = minorGridLineStyle;
    x.majorGridLineStyle = majorGridLineStyle;
    x.minorTickLineStyle = minorTickLineStyle;
    x.majorTickLineStyle = majorTickLineStyle;
    x.minorTicksPerInterval = 9;
    x.axisLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
    x.labelTextStyle = clearTextStyle;
    x.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithUpperOffset:0.0];
    x.coordinate = CPTCoordinateX;
    x.tickDirection = CPTSignNegative;

    NSNumberFormatter *labelFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    labelFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterNoStyle;
    x.labelFormatter = labelFormatter;

    // Y axis

    CPTXYAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;

    y.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic;

    // Y Axis at the beginning is at MAX_VALUE/2

    y.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromUnsignedInteger(MAX_VALUE/2);

    y.minorGridLineStyle = minorGridLineStyle;
    y.majorGridLineStyle = majorGridLineStyle;
    y.minorTickLineStyle = minorTickLineStyle;
    y.majorTickLineStyle = majorTickLineStyle;

    y.majorIntervalLength = CPTDecimalFromInt(10);
    y.minorTicksPerInterval = 3;

    y.labelAlignment = CPTAlignmentRight;

    y.axisLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
    y.labelTextStyle = clearTextStyle;
    y.labelFormatter = labelFormatter;
    y.coordinate = CPTCoordinateY;
}
```

When a new data is available:

```
- (void)newData:(int)data {

    CPTGraph *graphTop = self.hostViewTop.hostedGraph;
    CPTPlot *plotTop = [graphTop plotWithIdentifier:@"ID"];

    if (plotTop) {

        if (dataArray.count > MAX_DATA) {
            NSRange range;
            range.location = 0;
            range.length = dataArray.count-MAX_DATA;
            [dataArray removeObjectsInRange:range];
            [plotTop deleteDataInIndexRange:range];
        }

        CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpaceTop = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)graphTop.defaultPlotSpace;
        NSUInteger location = (currentIndex > MAX_DATA ? currentIndex - MAX_DATA + 1 : 0);

        CPTPlotRange *newYRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromUnsignedInteger(location)
                                                               length:CPTDecimalFromUnsignedInteger(MAX_DATA+MAX_DATA/4)];

        [plotSpaceTop setYRange:newYRange];

        currentIndex++;

        // minValue, maxVlue, avgValue calculated from al data visible in chart

        minValue = ...
        maxValue = ...
        avgValue = ...

        ...

        double delta;

        if (fabs(avgValue-minValue) > fabs(maxValue-avgValue)) {
            delta = fabs(avgValue-minValue);
        } else if (fabs(maxValue-avgValue)) {
            delta = fabs(maxValue-avgValue);
        }

        CPTPlotRange *newXRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble(avgValue-delta) length:CPTDecimalFromDouble(avgValue+delta)];

        [plotSpaceTop setXRange:newXRange];

        [((CPTXYAxisSet *) graphTop.axisSet).yAxis setOrthogonalCoordinateDecimal:CPTDecimalFromDouble(avgValue)];

        ...

        [plotTop insertDataAtIndex:newData.count - 1 numberOfRecords:1];

        ...
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Do you want the y-axis centered in the plot area in addition to crossing the x-axis at the average x-value?

Comment: Correct, and (to do that) I need to extend the range of the x axis to hold all the values in a proportionate manner so as to have the Y axis at the center

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `length` of the new `xRange` should be `delta * 2` to put the average value in the center.

```
CPTPlotRange *newXRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble(avgValue-delta)
                                                       length:CPTDecimalFromDouble(delta * 2.0)];
```

Comment: Yes correct, a lot of CorePlot code and I haven't seen that detail. Now is correct. Tanks a lot ;)